# Unable to execute MSCRM Webapi Custom Bound Action in mvc core using external wrapper (davidyack)

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, action

I'm unable execute a bound custom action in MSCRM using David Yack wrapper for mscrm webapi [github](https://github.com/davidyack/Xrm.Tools.CRMWebAPI/tree/master/dotnet). I can easily execute the Action using the MSCRM SDK libraries but as I'm using MVC core 2.2 these DLL are not available to me and the best alternative I have found is david's wrapper which is great albeit thin on the documentaion side.

I've tried various ways of executing the action. I am able to get working if the action is a unbound custom action with no parameters. I have had no luck on a entity bound action and passing parameters and the associated entity id.

I have tried finding a c# example on the documentation but this has proved difficult.

What I'm trying to achieve the the same functionality in the following SDK code below but using David's wrapper.

```cs
OrganizationRequest request = new OrganizationRequest("new_GetProductBuyPrice");
request["Target"] = new EntityReference("product", new Guid(ProductID));
request["Account"] = new EntityReference("account", new Guid(AccountID));
request["Currency"] = new EntityReference("transactionalcurrency", new Guid(CurrencyID));
request["Qty"] = 1.00m;

OrganizationResponse response = Xrm.XrmSvc.Execute(request);
UnitBuy = Math.Round(((Money)response.Results["BuyPrice"]).Value, 2);
DiscountReason = response.Results.Contains("DiscountReason") ? response.Results["DiscountReason"].ToString() : string.Empty;
```

How can I get david's wrapper to execute with my custom action in CRM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, managed to figure it out using David Yack API wrapper on [github](https://github.com/davidyack/Xrm.Tools.CRMWebAPI/tree/master/dotnet) and just posting my findings just in case anyone stumbles across this post. they key is to use a Dictionary as if it were the EntityReference class from the Microsoft SDK and use "@odata.type" as the entitytype and the entityid all lowercase as follows:

```
dynamic AccountRef = new Dictionary<String, object>();
            AccountRef["@odata.type"] = "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.account";
            AccountRef["accountid"] = AccountId.ToString();

            dynamic CurrencyRef = new Dictionary<String, object>();
            CurrencyRef["@odata.type"] = "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.transactioncurrency";
            CurrencyRef["transactioncurrencyid"] = CurrencyId.ToString();

            var actionParams = new
            {
                Account = AccountRef,
                Currency = CurrencyRef,
                Qty = 1.00m
            };
            var response = await _crmClient.API.ExecuteAction("Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.new_GetProductBuyPrice", "products", ProductId, actionParams);
```